# How to make a hybrid select + search field as one solid unit?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want to create a search field with an option to select some parameter before searching and it should look like one solid unit as on the picture below.

[image]

I didn't find such component in MaterialUI framework, which I'm using in my project. But maybe there is some third party solution for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Use custom css

```css
*{margin:0;padding:0}
.select{
  margin:0px;
  border-top-left-radius:25px;
  border-bottom-left-radius:25px;
  padding:10px;
}
.input{
  margin:0px;
  padding:10px;
  border-top-right-radius:25px;
  border-bottom-right-radius:25px;
}
```

```html
<select class="select">
  <option>One</option>
  <option>Two</option>
</select>
<input type="text" class="input" placeholder="Search"/>
```